# How to prevent the order of the apps location as it was before on MDM enrolled iPhone device?

Tags: ios, iphone, mdm

The order of the apps location is not coming the same as it was before applying the MDM policy to my iPhone device.

Comment: I have no idea what this means. You need to add a lot more detail with examples and show us the relevant code you are using

Comment: I am  restricting to use the apps through MDM policy and removing the apps from the iPhone device. But when i am removing the policy and the apps showing again on the device then the order of the apps has been changed. Apps are not coming in the order as it was before. Please help if you have any idea about this.

Comment: Are you talking about the ordering of the app icons on the phone homescreen? like they are in different folders and Facebook is now first on the left, where Twitter used to be first on the left and that kind of thing? If apps are uninstalled and reinstalled, they will appear in the order they start downloading. I don't think any MDM solution offers the ability to download apps one at a time in order to control where they show up. This would be a question for your MDM provider

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If you know any third party to provide this solution then please let me know.